# Custom Login Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I am new to django and i have a model that holds information about a account username password password salt.

models .py - has some RegExValdation on fields.

```
class modelName(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    password_salt = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, default=salt_generate)
```

I am wanting to take the password and Sha1Hash it with the password_salt field. Ive been searching and searching but i can't seem to find a way to do it. is it possible to do so within the model?

**password_salt is a randomly generated string of lowercase & uppercase letters with digits.

```
def salt_generate():
    while 1:
        from django.conf import settings
        import random, string
        pass_salt = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(32))
        try:
            Merchant.objects.get(password_salt=pass_salt)
        except:
            return pass_salt
```

With this model i am wanting to login a user to the application using the username and and password from this model.

I am a bit stumped as how to achieve this could someone please point me in the right direction I've seemed to be stuck on this for a while now.

I've been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFypO_LNmcc&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD
but i can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to implement your own account model from scratch, when django already has builtin [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) available for you?

Comment: Because Ive been asked to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't ever implement your own password hashing/user munging code. Statistically speaking, you'll get it wrong. From Django 1.5 onwards, you can simply import the BaseUse

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class YourUser(AbstractUser):
    my_field = TextField()
```

and then in your settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.YourUser'
```

Now you don't have to worry about passwords or hashing or security. They are taken care of by the very smart people who built django, and the rest of the 3rd party app ecosystem will play nice with your project too.

REF:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: Is it possible to have the Django User admin model as well as my custom user  model?

Comment: This way would subsume the django.contrib.auth user model. Essentially your user model would become THE user model for the system. I you want both, I would suggest subclassing the Django user model using normal model subclassing, then every YourUser would be a User, but not every User would be a YourUser. This may be closer to what you actually need, or not. Finally, you can always omit the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting entirely, and you would then indeed have both the vanilla auth.User model and your own model that would exist independently but you would get all of the security features of auth.

Answer (score -1):

You should use AbstractUser.

This is a very good example.

http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/03/django-15-subclass-abstractbaseuser.html